# OSError: -2, File "urequests.py", line 76, in request

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, oserror

I am working with Pi Pico W, it s already connected with Wi-Fi, can see the `ifconfig()` output.

Furthermore , I am using this urequests code from  https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/blob/master/python-ecosys/urequests/urequests.py, in yesterdays test almost every thinks was working fine. When tried to update records todays received below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 45, in <module>
File "request.py", line 10, in put_request
File "urequests.py", line 188, in put
File "urequests.py", line 76, in request
OSError: -2
```

I tried **check the Api server** from Postman but its working fine,**extend timeout** in request by 10 sec, even I **rebot pi.** nothing helping.

Dont know whats the cause !

request.py

```
import urequests
import json
import MSAL

def put_request(id, json_data): 
    
    url = 'url/{}'.format(id)
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': '{}'.format(MSAL.get_token())}

    response = urequests.put(url, data=json.dumps(json_data), headers=headers)
    print(response.text)
    response.close()
```

main.py

```
def send_data():
    global data
    print('gonna send req here')
    while True:
        while data:
            d = data.pop(0)
            print('This one Going', list(d.keys())[0], list(d.values())[0])
            request.put_request(list(d.keys())[0], list(d.values())[0])
            print('Left over', data)
            utime.sleep(0.5)
        utime.sleep(1)
```

Comment: could you post minimal code to reproduce your issue?

Comment: one idea- your URL is incorrect: `url = 'url/{}'.format(id)` will not be valid URL whatever you pass in `id` variable.

Comment: Hi @Lixas with same endpoint, I test on postman and worked pefect